# CI form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a function that should enable users to update their personal information and I'm using CI form validation library. I'd want to know if what I'm doing is right.

```
public function updateDetails()
{
    $this->load->model('users_model'); // load users model

    $username = $this->input->post("username", true); // get the post from view

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[32]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === true)
    {
        // Send to model
    }

}
```

Is this right? Or is there another method to do this?

Comment: Yes, right so far. You also need to respond to a failed validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes so far you're right 
but you should process if the validation is successful

```
public function updateDetails()
{
    // load the library if not already loaded in config/autoload.php
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[32]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === true)
    {
        $this->load->model('users_model'); // load users model
        $username = $this->input->post("username", true); // get the post from view
        // Send to model
    }
    else
    {
        $data['error_message'] = "form not valid ...blablabla";

        //go back to form
        $this->load->view("form_vew",$data);
    }

}
```